# NumDisparity is out of range.

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.2

I am getting block matching using tuning parameter.

I used the follow conditions for numDisparities.

```
if (bmTuneVar::numDisparities_slider < 16 )  bmTuneVar::numDisparities_slider = 16;

    if (bmTuneVar::numDisparities_slider % 16 == 0) bmTuneVar::numDisparities_slider+ 16;
```

When I get value from trackbar slider. I get 
bug that out of range. and numDisparities should be greater than 0and divided by 16.

that 's what I am checking my above statement. 
then I am not getting why its creating bug. 
anyone can please point out reason. 
thanks.

Comment: anyone can help me out.

Comment: `bmTuneVar::numDisparities_slider+ 16;` this statement doesn't do anything, does it?

Comment: if numDisparities are divisible by 16 then next value will be numDisparities_sldier + 16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I fixed it like this.

first initialize  `numDisparities_slider` and

```
numDisparities_maxValue
```

and set this value to bm and scale it with any value .

like below.

```
bm->setNumDisparities(numDisparities_slider * 16);
```

Hope this helps others too. 
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
if (bmTuneVar::numDisparities_slider % 16 == 0) bmTuneVar::numDisparities_slider+ 16;
```

Your idea here is to increase numDisparities_slider by 16?
then it should be

```
if (bmTuneVar::numDisparities_slider % 16 == 0) bmTuneVar::numDisparities_slider+=16;
```